# How do I match across newlines in a perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I'm trying to work out how to match across newlines with perl (from the shell). following:

```
(echo a b c d e; echo f g h i j; echo l m n o p) | perl -pe 's/(c.*)/[$1]/'
```

I get this:

```
a b [c d e]
f g h i j
l m n o p
```

Which is what I expect. But when I place an `/s` at the end of my regex, I get this:

```
a b [c d e
]f g h i j
l m n o p
```

What I expect and want it to print is this:

```
a b [c d e
f g h i j
l m n o p
]
```

Is the problem with my regex somehow, or my perl invocation flags?

Comment: I think, using `/s` should do the job. However, you can also use `[\S\s]*` instead of `.*`

Comment: @Rohit Jain: Not adequate: He's invoking Perl with the -p switch, and thus needs to enable slurp mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`-p` loops over input line-by-line, where "lines" are separated by `$/`, the input record separator, which is a newline by default. If you want to slurp all of STDIN into `$_` for matching, use `-0777`.

```
$ echo "a b c d e\nf g h i j\nl m n o p" | perl -pe 's/(c.*)/[$1]/s'
a b [c d e
]f g h i j
l m n o p
$ echo "a b c d e\nf g h i j\nl m n o p" | perl -0777pe 's/(c.*)/[$1]/s'
a b [c d e
f g h i j
l m n o p
]
```

See [Command Switches in perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) for information on both those flags. `-l` (dash-ell) will also be useful.

Comment: Compare `perl -MO=Deparse -0e1` with `perl -MO=Deparse -0777e1`. Changed your code to use the latter.

Comment: That worked exactly, and for my actual use case rather than this contrived example, too. Cheers :-) Saved me from having to write something custom in Ruby.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your one-liner works one line at a time, your regex is fine:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

my $s = qq|a b c d e
f g h i j
l m n o p|;

$s =~ s/(c.*)/[$1]/s;

say $s;
```

Answer (score 2):

There's More Than One Way To Do It: since you're reading "the entire file at a time" anyway, I'd personally drop the `-p` modifier, slurp the entire input explicitly, and go from there:

```
echo -e "a b c d e\nf g h i j\nl m n o p" | perl -e '$/ = undef; $_ = <>; s/(c.*)/[$1]/s; print;'
```

This solution does have more characters, but may be a bit more understandable for other readers (which will be you in three months time ;-D )

Answer (score 1):

Actually your one-liner looks like this:

```
while (<>) {

     $ =~ s/(c.*)/[$1]/s;
}
```

It's mean that regexp works only with first line of your input.

Answer (score 1):

You're reading a line at a time, so how do you think it can possibly match something that spans more than one line?

Add `-0777` to redefine "line" to "file" (and don't forget to add /s to make `.` match newlines).

```
$ (echo a b c d e; echo f g h i j; echo l m n o p) | perl -0777pe's/(c.*)/[$1]/s'
a b [c d e
f g h i j
l m n o p
]
```